# Las Vegas to Grand Canyon, Antelope and Zion in two days

Tags: road-trips, las-vegas, grand-canyon, arizona

We will be checking out of our Las Vegas hotel on Feb 14, and plan to spend two nights in and around the Grand Canyon visiting it, Antelope Canyon and Zion National Park. We have to return to Las Vegas on the afternoon of Feb 16 to catch a flight to San Francisco. We are thinking of booking a hotel in Tusayan for two nights and will rent a car in Las Vegas but want to know:

Is it possible to do it by bus instead?

Is it feasible for the mentioned season?

What kind of roads and weather can we expect?

Comment: @Dorothy: thanks for edit, but the location south of south rim is Tusayan right?

Comment: SORRY !!  Tiny tiny Tusayan but with great views :-) !!

Comment: Better make that two weeks rather than two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's technically feasible but unless you want to spend all you time driving with only time to take a picture at each location, maybe drop one.

Antelope and Zion are quite far from Las Vegas and would be a long day trip them selves.  Even Grand Canyon from Las Vegas is an entire day.

There are a number of operators that do guided (by bus) excursions to Grand Canyon from Las Vegas.  Zion probably as well, but I've not seen those specifically.

Staying in Tusayan, being on the south rim of the canyon, won't make much difference since that ~5hr drive from Las Vegas on it's own.

Because of the distance, you have 14 Feb  and 15 Feb to do one location each.  16 Feb, you'll need to leave mid morning to return to LAS.

Comment: Thanks, we are dropping Zion. On 14th we'll do Grand Canyon and on 15th we'll do Antelope Canyon. With hotel in Tusayan for both night.